# R Studio-0.99.451: how to unzip folder and paste files into destination folder

Tags: r, rstudio, geospatial

I am trying to extract(unzip) folder (namely "pakistan.zip" which contains 5 files Pak_admin0.shp, Pak_admin0.shx, Pak_admin0.dbf, Pak_admin0.prj, Pak_admin0.qpj) and copying the files of .shp, .shx, .dbf files from that folder to destination folder using Rstudio 0.99.451 version with the following codes:

```
for(j in list(".shp", ".shx", ".dbf"))
  {
  fname <- unzip(file=paste("pakistan", j, sep=""), zipfile= "pakistan.zip")
  file.copy(fname, paste("./pakistan", j, sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)
}

unlink("pakistan.zip")
```

but it gives me following error

```
Warning messages: 
1: In unzip(file = paste("zupanije", j, sep = ""), zipfile = "pakistan.zip") :   requested file not found in the zip file 
2: In unzip(file = paste("zupanije", j, sep = ""), zipfile = "pakistan.zip") :   requested file not found in the zip file 
3: In unzip(file = paste("zupanije", j, sep = ""), zipfile = "pakistan.zip") :   requested file not found in the zip file
```

Please provide any possible solution to deal with this error.
These are actual codes which I have found but zip.file.extract function is no longer part of R:

```
for(j in list(".shp", ".shx", ".dbf")){ 
fname <- zip.file.extract(file=paste("zupanije", j, sep=""), 
zipname="zupanije.zip") 
file.copy(fname, paste("./zupanije", j, sep=""), overwrite=TRUE) 
} 
unlink("zupanije.zip")
```

I want to automate the structure of downloading the shape file from website and unzip it and place into another folder then will display it using **maptools** library using **readShapePoly()** function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me for a zip file that contains those files.  The error suggests those files are not contained in the zip file. Since you say you are trying to extract a "directory" perhaps they are in a subdirectory in the zipfile?  For example, if I put the files in a "temp" directory and then create a zip file of that directory, I must add the directory to the file path, like this:

```
f <- "test.zip"
for(j in list(".shp", ".shx", ".dbf"))
{
  # note "pakistan" directory added to path
  # unzip pakistan/zupanije.shp (or .shx or .dbf) out of test.zip
  fname <- unzip(file=paste("pakistan/zupanije", j, sep=""), zipfile= f)
  #copy extracted file to destination directory
  file.copy(fname, paste("./destination", j, sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

If you are in a Linux like environment, you could try the following command to inspect the zip file and ensure it contains what you think it contains and at the path you expect:

`unzip -vl pakistan.zip`

By the way, your code will output the file "./pakistan/.dbf", "./pakistan/.shx" and "./pakistan/.shp".  Is that what you want?  Or do you perhaps want "pakistan.shx", etc. in which case this change is needed:

```
-file.copy(fname, paste("./pakistan", j, sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)
+file.copy(fname, paste("./pakistan", j, sep=""), overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: You are right the "pakistan" folder contains one subdirectory with same name "pakistan" in the zipfile but still i am unable to execute the code successfully. what is the parameter **zipfile=f** in your code. will you please add detail comments against each line of your code. I am not expert user in R.    Thanks

Comment: sorry. f is the zipfile name.  i will edit to clarify.

Comment: code run successfully now. I was doing all the time a common mistake that was to place the exact name of file in zip folder (i.e., in my case PAK_adm0.shp file) so i have to write the exact name in like fname<unzip(file=paste("pakistan/PAK_adm0", j, sep=""), zipfile=f).
Thank you so much for your kind effort to solve my problem. You can more add the detail comment for that matter in your answer to understand well.

Comment: I wrote following code these run successfully but these added 3 files extra into the pakistan folder which are named with .shp, shx, and .dbf. and the other three are what i need from this folder is PAK_adm0.shp, PAK_adm0.shx, and PAK_adm0.dbf. why other three files with only extension file are created or how to get rid of them.
`for(j in list(".shp", ".shx", ".dbf"))
{
  fname <- unzip(file=paste("PAK_adm0", j, sep=""), zipfile= 
  "PAK_adm_shp.zip",  exdir="pakistan")
  file.copy(fname, paste("./pakistan", j, sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)
}`